Heat Equation for fast source with FiPy
I'm trying to solve the following differential equation with FiPy, basically laser irradiation on a surface
$$
\rho_{s}C_{p,s}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k_{s}\frac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial x^{2}} + S(x,t) 
$$
$$
S(x,t) = \alpha_{s}\beta_{s}I(t)e^{(-\alpha_{s}x)}
$$
$$
I(t) = I_{0}(t/tp)^{7}e^{(7*(1-(t/tp)))}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \ = \frac{\beta I(t)}{k_{s}} - \frac{\epsilon \sigma (T^{4}-T_{0}^{4}) }{k_{s}}  \ at \ x \ = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \ = 0 \ at \ x \ = L 
$$
Where the s subscripts are the solid form of the target, where rho = 5170 (kg/m3), Cp = 590 (J/kgK), ks = 7.4 (W/mK), alpha=2.5E6 (1/m), beta=0.87, Ilaser=1.26E12 (W/m2), tp = 5e-9 (sec); trying to get something similar to the results of figure 3 in the following paper (https://www.mdpi.com/2072-666X/13/11/2012). I posted a similar problem a few weeks back and was instructed to try fipy. A snippet of my code can be seen here, where I've used some answers to similar fipy questions to store the results into arrays that can be plotted. The issue being that it seems to recreate the upswing of the curve just fine, but the downswing is seemingly ignored and there is no exponential decay despite the input being essentially a Gaussian function. The time and space steps are very small due to the time scale of my source. Apologies if this is a wall of text, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!
import fipy as fipy
rhos = 5170; Cps = 590; ks = 7.4; alphas = 2.5e6; beta = 0.87
Ilaser = 1.26e12
sig = 5.670374419*1e-8 #Stefan-Boltzmann constant
eps = 0.9 # aluminum emissivity
def I(t): # laser time dependent characteristic
    return Ilaser*((t/tp)**7)*fipy.numerix.exp(7*(1-(t/tp)))
delta = 1e-10 # penetration depth estimate
def Sdot(t): # laser source term
    return alpha*beta*I(t)*np.exp(-alpha*delta)
mesh = fipy.Grid1D(nx=100,dx=1e-6) # make 1D mesh
x = mesh.x # mesh coordinates
time = fipy.Variable(); 
tp = 5e-9; dt = tp/100
T= fipy.CellVariable(name="solution variable",mesh=mesh,value=T0,hasOld=True) 
T.constrain(valueLeft,where=mesh.facesLeft) # constrain left faces
T.constrain(valueRight,where=mesh.facesRight) # constrain right faces
 T.faceGrad.constrain(-Sdot(time)/(alpha*ks) -(eps*sig*(T**4 - T0**4)/ks), where=mesh.facesLeft)
T.faceGrad.constrain(0.,where=mesh.facesRight) # constrain boundary conditions on right face
 eqn1 = fipy.TransientTerm(coeff=rhos*Cps,var=T) == \
fipy.ExplicitDiffusionTerm(coeff=ks,var=T) + Sdot(time)
 steps = 301 # number of steps
  L = 1e-3 # length of space domain
 centerX=([L/2.],) # center
 TCenter = [T(centerX)[0]] # temperatures at cell centers
 ts  = [0.] # initial time list
 t = 0 # initial time
 for step in range(steps): #iterate
   time.setValue(t+dt/2.) # set time value
   T.updateOld()
   eqn1.sweep(var=T,dt=dt)
   TCenter.append(T(centerX)[0])
   t += dt # update time
   ts.append(t) # append updated time
 ts = np.array(ts) # make array 
 plt.figure() # figure
 plt.plot(ts*1e9, TCenter,'*-') # plot center temperatures vs time
 plt.grid(); plt.xlabel('Time (ns)'); plt.ylabel('T at center (K)')


Can you describe your time-stepping scheme mathematically? It seems that you have written your own. Since the temporal behavior is erroneous, this is likely the source of the error

@whpowell96 My understanding is the time stepping is taken care of 'under the hood' within the fipy time stepper. I might be wrong but this being a variant of the 1-D diffusion equation is described here (https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh1D.html). The smallest stable time step is (dx^2)/(2D), where D = k/(rhoCp); the dt I chose is much much smaller than this (5e-11 seconds vs ~9.5e-8 seconds). Time stepping sounds reasonable but not sure how that might be fixed.

Your code does not run since values are missing.
T0, valueLeft, valueRight, alpha If you can share your full code, it will be better to look into.

Also, show us a figure that shows the output and explain to us how it differs from what you think it should be!
